# how to remove div if count bigger than x with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, size

i have this html:

```
<div class="test">
   <div class="itsme">1</div>
   <div class="itsme">2</div>
   <div class="itsme">3</div>
   <div class="itsme">4</div>
</div>
```

and i am adding a new div dynamically with an ajax call at the top of div1.

```
var count = jQuery('div.itsme').size();
if(count > 3){
   $('.test').find("div:last").remove();
}
```

this works in a way that if i add one div , the last one gets removed, but it doesn't really keeps track of how many divs.

Even if there are 10 divs in the beginning , once i add another one the last one gets removed.

Why i am looking for is there to be always, in this case, 3 divs displayed. If i add another div then the last one gets removed, if i add 2 divs then the last 2 get removed

i hope i am clear enough.

thanks,

p.s. I am using `size()` because `lenght()` doesn't seem to work, chrome see it as an undefined function, and i checked, i have jquery 1.7..

Comment: [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) is not a function. Call it as a property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if($('.itsme').length > 3){
   $('.itsme:gt(2)').remove();
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Z8wDn/1/)

Comment: This will still only remove one div and then exit.  You need to use a for or while loop to remove divs until only 3 remain.

Comment: @Simon - You are right, but if appending one element at a time and then running the if statement I would go for :last, otherwise I changed my answer to remove all elements above a certain index.

Comment: Checking the length first is superflous. If there aren't more than three elements the result will be empty, and no elements are removed.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `:gt` selector to filter out the elements above a specific index, and remove them. This will keep only the three first elements:

```
$('.test .itsme:gt(2)').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just iterate like this:

```
var count = jQuery('div.itsme').size();
if (count > 3) {
  var numTimes = count - 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++) {
    $('.test').find("div:last").remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the last div with this selector

```
$('.itsme').eq(-1).remove();

$('.itsme') // select all the class

eq(-1) // select one element from the array of class begin for the end.
```

Edit:

If you want delete all the div minus three first class itsme use a bucle:

```
for( var i=0; i< $('.itsme').length - 3; i++){
     $('.itsme').eq(-1).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

that is because you only remove last one

try this:

```
jQuery('div.itsme:gt(2)').remove() // it starts at index 0
```